# Python plot : legend text on the same line

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend

I am trying to plot after reading files through a `for` loop and extracting a
variable *v* from each reading. This variable *v* I'm using to put different `label`s for different files. The particular in my case is

```
ax.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], linewidth=4.0, label='$v$ = {} $U$'.format(V))
```

And for the legend part I have just used `plt.legend(loc='upper left')`.

However, the legend labels don't appear on one line, rather they split and adjust with next lines.

[image]

Can *U* be placed on the same line where *v* is? I tried `borderpad=2` for the legend, but to no avail!

Comment: It all depends on what `V` is. But you keep that secret in your question.

Comment: You can easily spot `V` is a variable that takes values 0.1 and 0.2 in two iterations. The main code is too big.

Comment: What I mean is that the reason you get the linebreak is **inside `V`**.

Comment: Replied below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what `V` is. By default, there is never a linebreak in the legend label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
V = 0.1
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1], [2,1], linewidth=4.0, label='$v$ = {} $U$'.format(V))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You might get a linebreak if you have a linebreak in `V`, e.g. `V = "0.1\n"`. In this case you have to remove it before formatting the label.

Comment: To be frank, I have used ` V=subprocess.check_output('echo %s | cut -f2 -dV | cut -f1 -dU' %datafile, shell=True)` to extract `V` from `datafile`. Does the shell command leave an implicit new line?